# How can I send the logs from the jwilder/nginx-proxy docker image to logstash?

Tags: docker, nginx, logstash, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I tried adding the following to a `my_proxy.conf` file that gets mounted into  `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` in the container as described in https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy#custom-nginx-configuration but the logs aren't making into logstash.

Initially I added this to the conf file:

```
http {
  # Custom log format that also includes the host that processed the request
  log_format logstash '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$host" '
                  '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                  '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

  # Send logs to Logstash
  access_log syslog:server=logstash:5140,tag=nginx_access logstash;
  error_log syslog:server=logstash:5140,tag=nginx_error notice;
}
```

but when I start the container it tells me `"http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/my_proxy.conf:11`

So now I just have

```
# Custom log format that also includes the host that processed the request
log_format logstash '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$host" '
                  '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                  '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

# Send logs to Logstash
access_log syslog:server=logstash:5140,tag=nginx_access logstash;
error_log syslog:server=logstash:5140,tag=nginx_error notice;
```

which doesn't get any complaints when starting nginx, but doesn't put anything into logstash either. From here I don't know how to troubleshoot.

Comment: Please, share your logstash configuration too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syslog doesn't run in your container, so it doesn't make sense to use it for logging. Your options:

1.) Configure `gelf` logging driver on the Docker daemon level:

> Writes log messages to a Graylog Extended Log Format (GELF) endpoint such as Graylog or Logstash.

Doc: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/

2.) Start/configure dedicated logging container, which will send data for selected container(s) to logstash. See `Logspout` or other similar tools.

Tool: https://github.com/gliderlabs/logspout

Answer (score 0):

What I did was modify the `nginx.tmpl` file, which is the template used to generate `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`.

I added a line to everywhere `access_log` appeared.  For example:

```
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
  access_log syslog:server=111.222.111.222:1025 custom;
```

I defined the `custom` format next to the other format.  Eg.

```
log_format vhost '$host $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                 '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                 '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';


log_format custom '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]'
                  '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent'
                  '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"'
                  '"$request_time" "$upstream_connect_time"';
```

And then mount `nginx.tmpl` into the container.  eg.

```
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./config/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx.tmpl:/app/nginx.tmpl
      - ./logs:/var/log/nginx
```

To verify, restart nginx-proxy, bash into the nginx-proxy container and look at the generated `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`.

That's the idea.  It'd be nice to be able to specify the syslog URL somewhere instead of having to manually copy paste into `nginx.tmpl`.

Note this does work despite Jan's point about syslog not working inside a container.  Don't know why, It Just Works™